# Can we extend the repositories for which unattended upgrades are enabled?

Tags: unattended-upgrades

The usual advice regarding enabling unattended upgrades for some repository is to edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` and manually add the appropriate `Origin` values. I wonder whether one can add to this list by specifying multiple `Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins` blocks, or does any subsequent block override previous ones?

---

The use case is a local repository, which is added to the system by installing a package. I would like to enable unattended upgrades by adding a `99local_repo_conf` file to the package, with an `Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins` block containing that repository's Origin data. Will such a block override previous entries and prevent unattended upgrades of Ubuntu repositories?

---

Apparently, even though I can't find any documentation of it, this is indeed the behaviour.

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*upgrades*     
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "CSE:trusty";
};

Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "05:00";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";

// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
};
...
$ sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run --debug
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['o=CSE,a=trusty', 'o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security']
pkgs that look like they should be upgraded: 
...
```

Of course, the fact that entries are concatenated maybe a property of APT's configuration syntax, and documentation related to `unattended-upgrade` needn't mention it.

Can anyone provide documentation corroborating this?